# Flatmap nested collection

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap

I have a list of objects, some of them can be collections. I would like to get a stream of plain objects.

```
List<Object> objects = List.of(1, 2, "SomeString", List.of(3, 4, 5, 6), 
    7, List.of("a", "b", "c"),
    List.of(8, List.of(9, List.of(10))));
```

I would like to get a stream with elements.

```
1, 2, "SomeString", 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "a", "b", "c", 8, 9, 10
```

I have tried

```
Function<Object, Stream<Object>> mbjectToStreamMapper = null; //define it. I have not figured it out yet!
objects.stream().flatMap(ObjectToStreamMapper).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I also checked an [example](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java-8-streams/stream-n-depth-to-flat-collection.html) which shows how to use a recursive function which flattens a collection. However, in this example `.collect(Collectors.toList());` used to keep an intermediate result. `Collectors.toList()` is a terminal operation, which will start processing the stream right away. I would like to get a stream, which I can iterate on later.

---

### Update

I agree with comments, it is a terrible idea to have a stream composed of objects of different nature. I just wrote this question for simplicity. In real life, it can be that I listen to different events, and process some business objects from incoming streams, some of them can send stream of objects, other - just single objects.

Comment: "I have a list of objects, some of them can be collections." Unless your actual objects have a more useful common supertype, there is very little you can actually use this list for - irrespective of the streams - without some kind of reflection. So the solution (nearly) unavoidably involves reflection.

Comment: are you sure, you need to store all of these objects in the same list? Sounds like a horrible idea to me

Comment: @LászlóStahorszki, Yes, I agree with you. Just for simplicity sake. For example, I need to process events, updatedEvents, complexEvents, and they come from different sources. As I wrote in update.

Comment: I'm quite sure you can create a common interface, which all of the list members can implement

Comment: Don't put such a mixture anywhere. Instead wrap the things in an object implementing a common interface containing the streaming method. Then you have `List<MyStreamableThing>` which is much nicer and can be processed with `objects.stream().flatMap(MyStreamableThing::toStream)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can recursively get the nested `stream` if the object being traversed is an instance of `Collection`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
       List<Object> objects = List.of(1, 2, "SomeString", List.of(3, 4, 5, 6),
            7, List.of("a", "b", "c"),
            List.of(8, List.of(9, List.of(10))));
       List<Object> list = objects.stream().flatMap(c -> getNestedStream(c)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static Stream<Object> getNestedStream(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Collection){
        return ((Collection)obj).stream().flatMap((coll) -> getNestedStream(coll));
    }
    return Stream.of(obj);
}
```

Comment: filtering is unnecessay here, as List.of accepts not null arguments. And even I pass List.of new ArrayList with nulls, it will work.

Comment: you do not need `c` if `obj` is not an instance of Collection

Answer (score 16):

```
class Loop {
    private static Stream<Object> flat(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Collection ?
                ((Collection) o).stream().flatMap(Loop::flat) : Stream.of(o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> objects = List.of(1, 2, "SomeString", List.of( 3, 4, 5, 6),
                7, List.of("a", "b", "c"), List.of(8, List.of(9, List.of(10))));

        List<Object> flat = flat(objects).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(flat);
    }
}
```

Please note `List.of(null)` throws NPE.

Answer (score 2):

Note, it's possible to define recursive methods in a field:

```
public class Test {
  static Function<Object,Stream<?>> flat=
    s->s instanceof Collection ? ((Collection<?>)s).stream().flatMap(Test.flat) : Stream.of(s);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    objects.stream().flatMap(flat).forEach(System.out::print);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved the code of accepted answer and it's working fine.

```
    <E> Stream<E> getNestedStream(E input, Function<E, List<E>> mapper) {
        if(Objects.isNull(input)) {
            return Stream.empty();
        }
        Collection<E> values = mapper.apply(input);
        if(Objects.isNull(values)) {
            return Stream.of(input);
        }
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(input), mapper.apply(input).stream().flatMap(obj -> getNestedStream(obj, mapper)));
    }
```